# Sparse Matrix Matrix multiplication using Intel MKL

Tags: sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

Let $D$ be a sparse matrix. I want to compute $D\times D^T$. As $D$ is fairly large, so I am row-slicing $D$. That means for a range $(i,j)$, I am computing $C = D(i:j,:) \times D^T$ and performing some post-processing on $C$. I am choosing the index according to my available memory. I want to know whether there is any built-in function for doing that in Intel MKL. What I am doing now is:

1. Pre-compute $D^T$.
2. For a row-slice $(i,j)$, compute CSR-handler for $D(i:j,:)$
3. $C = D(i:j,:) \times D^T$, using  **mkl_sparse_s_spmmd**

This approach uses extra memory to compute and save $D^T$ as a pre-processing step. I am using **spmmd** because the resultant matrix will be dense. **spmmd** allows us to take operation on the first matrix but not the second. There is also an **sp2m**, but in this case, the multiplied matrix is sparse. Any methods I have missed?

Comment: The usual question applies for matrix-matrix products: What do you actually need the product for? Couldn't you get away with just implementing the action?

Comment: Is there some way to pass a transposed view to the method? Since all you really have to do is flip the iteration indices for the transposed matrix, doing a full precomputation seems to waste memory.

Answer (score 1):

https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-mkl-sparse-syrk

This routine is specifically designed for your problem. It will output the upper half of the resulting matrix, which is often preferable.